# How many people would make up the HQ and Staff positions of an Army Corp size unit, and what would their roles be?

Tags: military, military-organisation

Deployed to defend the Republic of Kievansk, and with it the northern flank of the United Commonwealth forces on the continent of West Ursia, is the 18th Corp, the Sand Vipers. This unit, comprising so many sub units, from divions down to independent companies, would of course require a very large leadership section to control.

This leads me to my question: Just how many people would make up the necessary staff and other HQ positions of this formation, and other as large, and what sorts of roles and ranks they would hold.

**The size of the Formation**

Army Corps are based around 3 maneuver divisions, either Infantry or Armoured, and a host of sub units, such as Air, Signals, Artillery and Supply units, among others, usually of Regiment to battalion strength. There will also be certain units assigned to it from its parent Field Army.

**Staff System**

The staff system is based off the British Staff system, comprising of a Lt. Gen. as its Gen. Officer Commanding, a Chief Of Staff, ranked Brigadier, and 3 other officers as Operations, Adjudant (personnel ad administration) and Quartermaster (Supply and logistics) heads at least. However, outside of these 5, I'm sure there are still other important roles to filled.

Comment: A full modern Corps-size headquarters runs to several hundred positions, usually organized as a Headquarters Battalion.

Comment: The problem with trying to answer this question is that the answer depends on the political structure of the country. If the only functioning organization in the country is the military, it will have a huge organization. In other countries, the military might be lean but have many private companies embedded in the organization doing the work.

Answer (score 4):

**Your Decision**

Different national traditions have put a different emphasis on headquarters at different levels, and on coordination through common doctrine vs. coordination through explicit orders. Who decides if a corporal gets decorated for bravery? The regimental commander, a division staff officer, somebody at the corps level, or somebody back in the capital?

I would expect around 30,000 to 40,000 troops in the "frontline battalions" and **the same number** in the "support and staff units." Some of these are rather clearly "support" rather than "staff." Nobody would call a laundry and clothing exchange company a "staff" unit. But how about a map printing unit? An obscure branch of the engineers, or listed in the "staff" of the corps or division?

You will need a number of functions. The departments and sub-departments may vary.

- Personnel

  - Replacements and promotions
  - Pay.
  - Possibly mail is at this level.
  - Chaplains or other morale officers.
  - Military police, investigations branch.
- Plans

  - For current operations, at a corps level that might be "this week" or "next week."
  - For upcoming operations, say the next month. (Next year is planned from the capital.)
- Intelligence

  - Making sense of the own "frontline unit" reports.
  - Sending "special units" to collect information (recon patrols, recon planes?).
  - Counterintelligence.
- Logistics

  - Distributing what you have where it is needed.
  - Predicting what will be needed.
  - Finding and buying/requisitioning local sources.
  - Managing the use of road nets in "non-frontline" areas.
- Communications

  - Managing signal nets and codes.
  - Supporting the communications of the other departments.
- Command of "non-frontline" units.

  - Air planning staff.
  - Coordination of the corps-level artillery.
  - Coordination of the corps-level engineers.
  - Chemical defense?

You could easily have somewhere between platoon strength and company strength for each bullet point. But you could also have them formally outside the corps staff, grouping the corps artillery in a separate *Artillery Brigade (General Support)* with their own headquarters, or have the *Criminal Investigations* assigned to the MP Battalion rather than directly to the HQ, and so on.

As to rank, there are several issues:

- Reward experience with seniority beyond time-in-grade.
- Clarify succession to command in a crisis.
- Assure that the headquarters people are respected elsewhere.

A rifleman who commands nobody but himself would be called a *private*. So why is pilot of a single-seat plane an officer and not an *air force private*? Because he went through hard and specialized training, and because it wouldn't do to have an Army *commander of a dozen* (i.e. squad leader) rank the same as an Air Force *commander of a dozen* (i.e. squadron commander). You might want the pilot to outrank the maintenance chief, too, even if the maintenance for a fighter takes multiple people.

So many of the bullet points above probably need a [field-grade officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_officer) to ensure that they get the attention they deserve from the "frontline" company and battalion commanders. Each has a deputy, either field-grade or [company-grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_officer), and a bunch of company-grade assistants.

Comment: Who brews the tea? Perhaps that comes under "morale".

Comment: @ARogueAnt. the Sergeant Major will find a reliable, long-serving Lance Corporal. Couldn't leave such a vital task to officers.